# Cannot access paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been trying to access my Paypal Sandbox but no luck. I can login fine to my PayPal account but when I try to access https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hub/ or https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ I keep getting a page cannot be displayed error. I have flushed my cache and have tried IE, Firefox and Chrome but none seem to work.

None of the links from within PayPal to the sandbox work either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps behind some type of firewall or security setting that is blocking access.  What pages on the sandbox are you specifically trying to access.  Make sure you are signing into [PayPal's Developer Site](http://developer.paypal.com) first at (developer.paypal.com), and then try accessing one of your accounts you have set up by clicking the link under you test account that says access sandbox site.  Otherwise after signing into the developer account, you can open up another tab and go to the [sandbox site](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and see if that page comes up for you.  You should be able to sign in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but I could find a workaround.
If you pay attention in the links of the left menu (My business info, my money..), they are leading to pages in the domain "beta-sandbox" and that's the problem.

Copy the link and change the domain for "sandbox"

For instance, the correct link for

https://www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES

is

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES